# What does Rectangle.Intersect means/do?

Tags: xna-4.0, intersection

Ok I have two rectangles
one is the ball and other is the paddle.

```
1.    if(ball.rectangle.intersects(paddle.rectangle))
          y = -Math.Abs(y);
```

and

```
2.   if(paddle.rectangle.intersects(ball.rectangle))
        y = -Math.Abs(y);
       // y is y-axis of ball
```

are both of them same.
I used the (1.) code and when my bouncing ball touches the paddle it reflects as I want it too but when I use the (2.) code my bouncing ball it sticks with the paddle for some milliseconds then bounces off as I want it too.
I don't understand why they aren't the same. Can anybody tell me the difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

These are exactly the same and should be executed the same.
The intersects method only returns a bool when 2 rectangles intersect,
it does nothing more.

If the result isn't the same, it might have something to do with your other code. Maybe you can post it?